# Can you make Mobile Anniversary version of Windows 10 Mobile ask before updating?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update, lumia-640

I have multiple Android phones and one Windows Phone and iPhone for mobile developing purposes.

I have my main SIM is my best Android phone, but I keep my work SIM in Windows Phone.

Just now Windows rolled Mobile Anniversary update to my phone and ask before updating is missing.

There is only a time-frame you can set when it will not update, but that cant be set to over 18 hours.

It's annoying when I wake up and notice that phone has restarted, asks my PIN and I have missed multiple important calls.

I could make it not to update at night but I need it to be on also during work hours, so mostly 24/7.

Before it would ask me to update and I would update it after work, or when there are some down time.

Easiest solutions would be to put the SIM in some of my Android or iPhone phones, but I was curious if someone has found a solutions, I could not find find in setting or with googling the issue.

So if there is some  Windows 10 Mobile power user who knows the fix (or hack), that would be appreciated. :)

**Phone in question is Lumia 640 (RM-1072).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The things is Microsoft went for automatic installation of updates to prevent the [fragmentation problem](http://www.businessinsider.in/Androids-Massive-Fragmentation-Problem-In-Two-Handy-Charts/articleshow/21489340.cms) like Android. Users cannot completely stop the updates on the Windows mobile. But there are some points which can help you.

1. Windows 10 Mobile will install updates automatically over an
   unmetered connection only. If you use a mobile data on your phone it
   will not download the updates automatically.
2. If you are running on Insider preview you can pause the updates to upto 7days.
3. As you have mentioned you can set active hours for upto 18hours a day during which the update will not install. Although the updates will be downloaded regardless of that.
4. You can also set a custom restart time for updates to install. This works only after an update has been downloaded. I bet this will remind you to set a custom time if an update has finished downloaded within active hours. However It was just implemented in Aniversity update and I am not sure how it works.

On final note, you should get familiar with the Windows update schedule. The updates are released once in a month. Most of them are small installing within a 10mins time at max. Once every 6-8 months big updates such the aniversity updates will install. These updates take much more time to install.

Also I would like to note that your phone will receive calls during the Migrating data process of update although you cannot make calls.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will put my phone to use only mobile data. Problem with calls is that phone reboots after the update and my SIM needs PIN to been given before any calls come trough.

Comment: @SanteriHetekivi You are welcome.

Comment: And now I just removed my PIN on the SIM card so even if it still rebooted It would still receive calls. :)

Comment: @SanteriHetekivi Great.