# How to Cancel Downloading Updates for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10-mobile, update

I recently rolled back to Windows 8.1 and installed Windows 10. (this was because the anniversary update of windows 10 mobiles messed up my phone so I did a hard reset)

And I am perfectly happy with my current build of Windows 10. But now it is downloading updates (the anniversary update). How do I cancel it? I don't want an update.

Comment: Refer to this question here - http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13879/can-you-make-mobile-anniversary-version-of-windows-10-mobile-ask-before-updating/13881#13881